# k8s Module not recognizing environement variables on the remote machine - Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, cloud

I am trying to execute a k8s command, on a Rancher Machine, through an Ansible playbook. The problem is that I am having an error that says the "export" command does not exist on the remote machine, which does not make any sense. The error is:

```
"OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"export\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown\r\n"
```

This is very weird since every Linux machine has the export command by default. This is the same that saying "cd" can not be found.

I am using the export command in order to create the "$RETAIL_HOME" variable and, then, execute some commands on that directory.

Here is the playbook I am running:

```
---
- hosts: localhost #group of hosts on host file
  connection: local
  remote_user: redmine
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'
  collections:
    - community.kubernetes
  tasks:
      - name: Define Retail Home Path
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
        namespace: redmine
        pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
        command: export RETAIL_HOME=/u01/app/rms
    - name: Move to Retail_Home Directory
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
        namespace: redmine
        pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
        command: cd $RETAIL_HOME
    - name: execute rpatch to analyse the Patch
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
        namespace: redmine
        pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
        command: orpatch analyze -s /tmp/p{{ patch_id | mandatory }}_190000_Generic #passing the patch id as mandatory
    - name: ORPatch Apply
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
        namespace: redmine
        pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
        command: orpatch apply
```

Ansible Version:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

Comment: 2 points, I think you did not get the command is executed inside the pod in a container, and export is a not binary but it's provided by your shell, and there is no shell involved using k8s_exec

Comment: I don't get what you want to do, why would like to just run `export`, that does not do nothing, that makes no sense. Please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: I would want to run the export command in order to release an environment variable so that I can run a couple of commands on the directory defined by that environment variable, please take a look of my updated playbook, you will understand it better I think!

Comment: I had a similar problem with utilizing the "zip" command on the same machine. But, by installing it I got the problem workaround and solved it. But now, export is something already in the machine by default. I am a little bit lost here... Thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm sorry to I think you lack basic knowledge on containers, that make hard to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same difference between [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) and [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) modules applies on the `command` field of this module. What you trying to do is using shell properties which does not work.

Also, commands in different `k8s_exec` tasks won't help because, they are not related, so exporting a variable in a first task won't make it available on next tasks, You should put everything on one command.

```
- name: Define Retail Home Path
  k8s_exec:
    kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
    namespace: redmine
    pod: "{{ pod_name | mandatory }}" #pod name
    command: |
      orpatch analyze -s /tmp/p{{ patch_id | mandatory }}_190000_Generic
      orpatch apply
    environment:
      RETAIL_HOME: /u01/app/rms
```

Comment: But, if I cannot use the k8s exec to use shell commands, how do I use shell commands, such as the export one?

Comment: Is there any way to run as a shell with k8s_module? Any workaround? Thanks in advance